# DNNClassifier Tensorflow related classification queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, classification

I have input and output in the csv: [training.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/3ab8ee88f3fc32e78579a1054aac757d#file-training-csv)
The output is in the form of `-1,0, or 1` as one can see the output column.
The  following is the code that I am using for `DNNClassifier`:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
import csv
import os
print(os.listdir("input"))

data = pd.read_csv("training.csv")
data = data.fillna(0)
print((data.columns))

data[:-1] = data[:-1].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max()-x.min()) )

feat_cols=[]
for i in range(len(data.columns)-1):
    feat_cols.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(data.columns[i]))

data['output'] = data['output'].astype('int64')
data.info()

input_x = data.drop('output',axis=1)
input_y = data['output']

input_x.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_x, input_y, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 0)

# write an input function
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=True,target_column="output")

# Dense neural network means every neuron is connected to every neuron in the next stage
dnn_model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,10], feature_columns=feat_cols, n_classes=3,model_dir="DNN1",        
                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001) )
# no need to create embedded columns, all columns are already embedded

# PULL THE LEVER, KRONK!
output = dnn_model.train(input_fn=input_func, steps=1000)
print("this is output====>   ",output)

# Evaluate the model
eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False,)
results = dnn_model.evaluate(eval_input_func)
print(results)

# Make some predictions
pred_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train, batch_size=10, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
predictions = dnn_model.predict(pred_input_func)
my_pred=list(predictions)

for i in predictions:
    print(i)

data1 = pd.DataFrame(my_pred)

data1.head()

data1.to_csv("pred_class.csv")
```

When the `n_classes = 3`, I get the output as: [Gist holding the output](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/0ec64009fad4d4cb398135cccc58615d)
When the `n_classes = 2`, I get the output as: [Gist holding the output](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/ad023894942ca980b4e7f269ae3b6098)

The questions I have:

> 1) When `n_classes = 3`, I see the columns containing `logit`, but when `n_classes=2` I see extra column as `logistic`. Why is it like this? What is the purpose of this separate column?
>
> 2) Why the classifier is not classifying the output in the form of 3 as the output column has 3 different outputs?
>
> 3) Whether the classifier is predicting the next step of the output or the corresponding result in the `output` column?
>
> 4) Which is my output column so that I can check the output of the prediction? Is it `logit` or `logistic`?

Kindly, suggest me. And I hope that my question is crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

For 3 classes, the final output layer would treat the probability distribution as a multinomial variable while for 2 classes, it will be a binary variable.

Logits in ML refer to non-normalized log probabilities obtained on application of softmax function. Logistic refers to application of something like the sigmoid activation function for binary classification to produce something similar to a probability. If you normalize and scale your logits by taking the exponent, you will get the probabilities column in the case of 3 classes. In case of 2 classes, you can see the probabilities output corresponds to your logistic output as 1-p and p. In the case of 2 classes, often you can afford to have only a single output node as the result is 0/1 type. Which is why you see 2 kinds of results.

The outputs are always in terms of probabilities of each class. You can see which class the network thinks this input belongs to by looking at the output node corresponding to maximum probability. But often, you will measure how well your system is doing by looking at whether your expected output is in the top so many outputs the system thinks this particular data point is. So we have probabilities to see if its not the first guess, maybe its the second and if so with what confidence and so on.
So your output can be inferred from the probabilities column. the classes column also correspondingly tells the same thing by inferring which probability is the maximum.

Comment: That's a cool answer. Guess my activation function isn't `softmax`, its `relu`. Still I can understand from the points that you have inferred in the answer. Thank you for the explanation